# Código TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Então galera, eu estou fazendo uma pagina html em que eu estou usando o TypeScript, e eu não estava conseguindo pegar o value de um id, até que eu vi em uma pegunta no stack que deveria ser usado desta forma

```
(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('ID')).value
```

para pegar o value. Eu sei que no JavaScript é mais simples... não precisa do `<HTMLInputElement>`.

Vocês podem me explicar por que eu preciso usar isso e como seria um jeito mais fácil pra mim, que estou fazendo um código com muitas variáveis, poder usar as variáveis sem ter que ficar digitando da forma do primeiro exemplo.

**OBS:** Não seria prático pra mim colocar desta forma:

```
var exemplo = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('EXEMPLO')).value;
```

pois tem lugares que eu preciso usar o mesmo ID para fazer outra coisa, que nao seja pegar o value... como:

```
(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('EXEMPLO')).checked = true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque você precisa usar isso?

É porque o método `getElementById` retorna um `HTMLElement` ou `null`. `HTMLElement` é uma classe que não possui a propriedade `value`, por isso, se você quiser acessar tal propriedade, você precisa fazer um cast no elemento para trata-lo como um `HTMLInputElement`, classe a qual estende `HTMLElement` e possui a propriedade `value`.

Casting não é uma operação segura, não tem como garantir em tempo de compilação que o elemento encontrado é de fato um `HTMLInputElement`, e portanto idealmente você deveria usar smart cast, como no exemplo:

```
const elem = document.getElementById('ID');
const elemValue = elem instanceof HTMLInputElement ? elem.value : '';
```

Como a condição assegura que o elemento encontrado é de fato um `HTMLInputElement`, você pode acessar as propriedades de um `HTMLInputElement` sem que o compilador acuse erros, e não há riscos de erro em tempo de execução. Isso também funciona com `if`s

```
if (elem instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
    // ...
}
```

Como você pode tornar isso menos verbose?

Desativando a opção no `tsconfig.json`. Apesar da verbosidade, não recomendo você fazer isso, pois estaria derrotando o propósito de tipagem segura do TypeScript. Esse é um dos comprometimentos que você precisa fazer para utilizar a linguagem.

Answer (score 0):

Você está usando vários lugares um ID? 
Id é único, se você quiser usar em vários lugares deve usar classe

```
document.getElementsByClassName('EXEMPLO').value
```

Comment: não estou usando em vários lugares no html.... mas tenho que chamar em lugares diferentes no TypeScript... então fico repetindo o código `(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('ID')).value`, acaba que o código fica confuso

Comment: É para pegar o valor mais atual? se não é só usar uma variável, é open source? poderia postar um exemplo, se o projeto é grande seria melhor usar algum framework como angular ou uma lib como jquery / react .